# React node app with fuse-box, TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm building React and Node(express) app using [fuse-box](http://fuse-box.org/)

`const ap = express()` is causing this error:

```
`path/to/projct/react/react-skeleton/build/ssr/development/bundle.js:7624
    require("./streams")(iconv);
                        ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
.
.
.`
```

Here is the babel configs of the fuse.js file:

```
let  babelPresetEnv = [
  'env',
  {
    targets: {
      browsers
    },
  }
]

_.BabelPlugin({
  config: {
    sourceMaps: true,
    presets: ['react', 'stage-0', babelPresetEnv],
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy',
      'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
      'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
      'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread',
      'babel-plugin-transform-object-assign'
    ].map(require.resolve)
  }
}),
```

I totally failed to fix it.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, finally downgrading express solved it:
`"express": "4.15.4",`